# Localtunnel: Unable to register tunnel. Perhaps service is down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting, localtunnel

I tried running localtunnel with this command:

```
localtunnel 3000
```

and got this error:

```
[Error] Unable to register tunnel. Perhaps service is down?
```

Is the service down or is there something I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

localtunnel has been down for a while now

- https://github.com/progrium/localtunnel/issues/105
- https://github.com/progrium/localtunnel/issues/98

Try [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) as an atlernative

Answer (score 0):

Use similar service which works:
https://pagekite.net